# Creating Child Object, Child Constructor Not Used OOP

Tags: java, oop, parent-child, createobject

I'm a beginner to java, and I'm having issues creating an object that is a child of a parent class. I can't share source code, because it is for a school project; and I don't want to get dinged for cheating. But, I can write similar code; so that I can gain a fundamental understanding to the concepts that I am not grasping.

Java Environment: Eclipse

When I am attempting to create an child object in my Test class, I'm getting an error (that red symbol in the line numbers).

The error message that I'm receiving is "The constructor Animal(Long, String, Float, String, String) is undefined. Then the suggestions offer two options, modify the Animal constructor to include the child Dog class parameters. Or, create a new Animal constructor with the Animal and child Dog class parameters.

I'm not sure why this is happening. I've double checked and I'm not getting errors at the child constructors; and I'm using "super()". I thought that OOP and Java would automatically create a child object with the matching parameter pattern. Any help would be appreciated.

Parent Class

```
pubic class Animal {
   Long id;
   String section;
   Float price;

   public Animal (Long id, String section, Float price){
        this.id = id;
        this.section = section;
        this.price = price;
   }
}
```

1st Child Class

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
   String name;
   String favoriteToy;

   public Dog (Long id, String section, Float price, String name, String favoriteToy){
         super(id, section, price);
         this.name = name;
         this.favoriteToy = favoriteToy;
   }
}
```

2nd Child Class

```
public class Bird extends Animal {
   String name;
   Integer wingSpan;

   public Dog (Long id, String section, Float price, String name, Integer wingSpan){
         super(id, section, price);
         this.name = name;
         this.wingSpan = wingSpan;
   }
}
```

Test Class

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{
         //I get error here
         Animal animal1 = new Animal (Long.valueOf(76532), "Canine", 99.95, "Sparky", "tennis ball");
   }
}
```

Comment: The simple answer is that this: `new Animal (Long.valueOf(76532), "Canine", 99.95, "Sparky", "tennis ball")` does not match this: `public Animal (Long id, String section, Float price)`.  They must match or it's no-go.

Comment: Hint: it looks like you meant "new Dog" instead of "new Animal".

Comment: Aside: you can create a `long` literal like this: 76532L.  The call to `Long.valueOf` is kind of gauche.  But 76532 is small enough that you don't have to do either, it will be auto-promoted with no fuss.

Comment: Shouldn't I be just calling the parent constructor, and the child constructors would automatically match to the parameter pattern? I thought that was the point of OOP. I'm declaring the "super" key word in the child classes.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I was correct about the parent-child constructor relationships. There were some other parameter types that were not matching. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @markspace, thanks for the tip about the Long number.

Comment: No, it's the other way around.  You call the child constructor, and the parent is automatically invoked.  That's what `super` does.  Calls go up the tree, not down it.  (Otherwise, if the call goes down the tree, how would the system know, when you call `new Animal`, whether you wanted a `Bird` or a `Dog`?

Comment: " I thought that OOP and Java would automatically create a child object with the matching parameter pattern" - Nope. State what child you want to have.

Comment: Was my answer helpful for you? If so, you may want to accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Animal` class has exactly one constructor

```java
public Animal (Long id, String section, Float price){
```

but you're calling a constructor

```java
new Animal (Long.valueOf(76532), "Canine", 99.95, "Sparky", "tennis ball");
```

This constructor does not exist for `Animal`. It is exactly what the compiler told you with *"The constructor Animal(Long, String, Float, String, String) is undefined"*. What exists is

```java
public Dog (Long id, String section, Float price, String name, Integer wingSpan){
```

that is a constructor of your `Dog` class. You probably want to call *that* like

```java
new Dog (Long.valueOf(76532), "Canine", 99.95, "Sparky", "tennis ball");
```

As `Dog` inherits from `Animal`, i.e. `Dog` *is an* `Animal`, you can store a `Dog` reference in a variable of type `Animal` like

```java
Animal animal1 = new Dog (Long.valueOf(76532), "Canine", 99.95, "Sparky", "tennis ball");
```